# How do you construct "whose name is X" style statements in macruby/scriptingbridge?

Tags: macruby

In applescript:

```
set allItems to every item whose name is "foo"
```

In rb-appscript:

```
all_items = items[its.name.eq "Foo"]
```

Is there a way to construct a similar search/predicate/what-have-you in MacRuby/ScriptingBridge?

Answer (score 0):

Problem: solved!

```
predicate = NSPredicate.predicateWithFormat %(name = "Foo")
all_items = items.filterUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

[Handy reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).